# animate({width: 'toggle'}) jumps if the element contains text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that I show and hide columns in. I'm using the following code to "animate" the column toggling:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(' + 2 + ')').animate({width: 'toggle'});
```

This works fine if the column doesn't have text in it, but if it does have text, the "toggle" gets jumpy. ([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SRnV3/))

Is there a way to smoothly slide the column in and out of existence?

Comment: issue comes from you are using a table, see: http://jsfiddle.net/SRnV3/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff Of course, by changing the display from `table-cell` to   `inline-block`, it's not behaving like a table anymore.  http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/SRnV3/2/

Comment: @Blazemonger ya and that's the issue, animating a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because the slide effect progressively reduce the space of the cell so the text jump down and with a table element as is and without any modification it's a side effect.

You can consider to use another effect that not alter the width like `fadeToggle`.

Code:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('table tr td:nth-child('+2+')').fadeToggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X2b2c/